# Careers 2.0 Bug: City of O'Fallon, Illinois Becomes Tjele, Denmark

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, location

When I enter the city of O'Fallon IL (US) as my location, it shows up as Tjele, Denmark in my profile.

Comment: There's a simple solution - move to Tjele, Denmark! :P

Comment: You've discovered a wormhole.

Comment: They're practically right next to each other, I can see how the algorithm could get tripped up.  Or maybe Denmark has established an exclave in Illinois?

Comment: Candidates who said they were interested in O'Fallon, Illinois were also interested in these cities...

Comment: This old bug was clearly fixed at some point in the last (almost) 3 years.

Comment: yes, fixed shortly after I posted this back then.

Comment: There is a postal/ZIP code, [8830](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postnumre_i_Danmark#%C3%98stjylland_(8000-8999)), with the name Tjele, but not an actual place called that, except for [the manor](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tjele_Gods) from which other place names in that area have been derived, like [the municipality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tjele_Municipality) that ceased to exist before Stack Overflow was born.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed. They fixed the error not too long after I posted this.